# Use class or struct for representing millions of entities?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

### Scenario

- working in memory with millions of entities (or even more)
- processing in infinite tight loop (max. 1ms per tick)
- fast load and save to binary files
- lot of chained method calls with the entity as parameter

I cannot instantiate all the entities. The allocation cost would be too much. I will load them into byte[] array and only use them when needed.

### Class solution

```
public class Entity : IDisposable
{
    public Pool Pool { get; }

    private readonly int _size;

    private int _id;

    private int _offset;

    private readonly Property[] _properties;

    private readonly byte[] _tape;

    public int Id
    {
        get => _id;
        set
        {
            _id = value;
            _offset = value * _size;
        }
    }

    public int Value1
    {
        get => GetInt32(0);
        set => SetInt32(0, value);
    }

    public int Value2
    {
        get => GetInt32(1);
        set => SetInt32(1, value);
    }

    public Entity(Pool pool)
    {
        Pool = pool;
        _size = pool.Schema.Size;
        _properties = pool.Schema.GetProperties();
        _tape = pool.Tape;
    }

    public int GetInt32(int index)
    {
        var offset = GetOffset(index);

        return _tape[offset] << 24 |
               _tape[offset + 1] << 16 |
               _tape[offset + 2] << 8 |
               _tape[offset + 3];
    }

    public void SetInt32(int index, int value)
    {
        var offset = GetOffset(index);

        _tape[offset] = (byte)(value >> 24);
        _tape[offset + 1] = (byte)(value >> 16);
        _tape[offset + 2] = (byte)(value >> 8);
        _tape[offset + 3] = (byte)value;
    }

    private int GetOffset(int index)
    {
        var property = _properties[index];

        return _offset + property.Offset;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Pool.Release(this);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
while(true)
{
    using(var entity = pool.Lease())
    {
        entity.Id = 123;
        entity.Value1 = entity.Value2 + 123;
        DoSomething1(entity);
        DoSomething2(entity);
    }
}
```

### Struct solution

```
public struct Entity
{
    public Pool Pool { get; }

    private readonly int _size;

    private int _id;

    private int _offset;

    private readonly Property[] _properties;

    private readonly byte[] _tape;

    public int Id
    {
        get => _id;
        set
        {
            _id = value;
            _offset = value * _size;
        }
    }

    public int Value1
    {
        get => GetInt32(0);
        set => SetInt32(0, value);
    }

    public int Value2
    {
        get => GetInt32(1);
        set => SetInt32(1, value);
    }

    public Entity(Pool pool)
    {
        Pool = pool;
        _size = pool.Schema.Size;
        _properties = pool.Schema.GetProperties();
        _tape = pool.Tape;
    }

    public int GetInt32(int index)
    {
        var offset = GetOffset(index);

        return _tape[offset] << 24 |
               _tape[offset + 1] << 16 |
               _tape[offset + 2] << 8 |
               _tape[offset + 3];
    }

    public void SetInt32(int index, int value)
    {
        var offset = GetOffset(index);

        _tape[offset] = (byte)(value >> 24);
        _tape[offset + 1] = (byte)(value >> 16);
        _tape[offset + 2] = (byte)(value >> 8);
        _tape[offset + 3] = (byte)value;
    }

    private int GetOffset(int index)
    {
        var property = _properties[index];

        return _offset + property.Offset;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
while(true)
{
    var entity = new Entity(pool);
    entity.Id = 123;
    entity.Value1 = entity.Value2 + 123;
    DoSomething1(entity);
    DoSomething2(entity);
}
```

### Conclusion

What is better, the class solution, or the struct solution? What all should I consider in my situation?

Comment: What's your definition of "better"? And: either solution seems overengineered to me.

Comment: I mean better in terms of performance.

Comment: In that case: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: I can measure it now, but when the system becomes larger, it could possibly change the conditions. So, I'm asking if someone experienced could point me in the right direction :)

Comment: BTW: If that code does not run in several threads, there's only going to be exactly one instance of `Entity`, ever. So, you might as well just create some static methods around that "_tape" byte array for convenience.

Comment: ... but in the end: there is _so much_ we do not know about your project, that (usable) advice is really hard to give. It's also unclear what (if at all) scaling options you have. So we cannot even suggest anything in that direction ...

Comment: It will be single threaded and probably mainly used as TCP/IP server for a PC game. I want to be able to handle 10.000.000 game objects and 10.000 players.

Comment: A single threaded TCP/IP Server - I would expect to have different bottlenecks than this here, then :D

Comment: This question sounds like "How do i do the same thing a multimillion dollar game company does with a large experienced dedicated network team as a single developer without prior knowledge just by asking Stackoverflow".

Comment: I was playing with the Socket.BeginListen, BeginReceive etc. It seems to me usable. I can collect the data into ConcurretQueue and then process them on single thread. I think I have some knowledge. Of course, it probably takes me a lot of years.

Answer (score 3):

You have the prototype. Measure the performance/memory usage, and compare the results. Choose whatever works best for your application.
If you have a byte array of data, consider using different [conversion methods](https://www.genericgamedev.com/general/converting-between-structs-and-byte-arrays/) between byte arrays and objects.
Consider using [Span](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=net-7.0) - which is a ref struct and should combine the advantages of both structs and classes.

Comment: I will definitely consider using Span (have to read about it first). I was trying using the BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32Big and also Marshal.ReadInt32, but it seems to give a very similar result as manual conversion.